# get JS (mouseover,mouseleave) to display different text over images in html document

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to get Javascript do display text whenever someone hovers onto an image. I have a grid of 8 images each with distinctive id. I'm learning JS that's why I'm trying to do it this way. 
So the problem is that I can only get all text/titles to display  at once, no matter which image I'm hovering over. I'd appreciate some guidance in clean JS as I'm a beginner. Thnak you in advance

so I have tried getElementById with a for loop but as said earlier it only dispalys all text at once. I have no clue how to  progress.

HTML

```
<ul class="car-parts">
<li>
<figure>
<img id="pic-one"  src="resources/img/1.exhaust.jpg" alt="exhaust 
                                                        repairs">
  <h4 class="text-block" >exhaust repairs</h4>
</figure>
</li>  
<li>
<figure>
  <img id="pic-two" src="resources/img/2.engine.jpg" alt="engine 
                                                    diagnostics">
    <h4 class="text-block" >exhaust repairs</h4>
</figure>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var pictures = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight'];

var x = document.querySelectorAll('.text-block');
for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
x[i].style.opacity = "0";

document.getElementById(                                                  
'pic-' +pictures[i]).addEventListener('mouseover',function(){    
for(var i=0; i <pictures.length; i++){
x[i].style.opacity = "1";    
x[i].style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";}
})};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see closures, variable scope, let vs var)

```
let pictures = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'];

let x = document.querySelectorAll('.text-block');
for (let i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.opacity = "0";

  document.getElementById(
    'pic-' + pictures[i]).addEventListener('mouseover', ()=> {
    for (let i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.opacity = "1";
      x[i].style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Hi Eugene
I'm getting parsing error at first line: unexpected token pictures. Any thoughts?

Comment: let pictures = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'];

error: parsing error: unexpected token pictures

I changed let back to var and the same error comes at line with

let x = document.querySelectorAll('.text-block');

Basically all let variables throws that error only after changing back to var code works, however not as intended

Comment: If you stil have problems we can arrange a extended discussion to solve you problem some time

Comment: well i haven't figured how to do it with JS so i'd be keen for that. I'm available any day after 6pm UK time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this kind of functionality completely with CSS. No need for Javascript. See the snippet below. I am changing the opacity of `h4` tags from 0 (invisible by default) to 1 whenever the mouse hovers over the figure.

```css
h4 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
figure:hover h4 {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<ul class="car-parts">
<li>
<figure>
<img id="pic-one"  src="resources/img/1.exhaust.jpg" alt="exhaust 
                                                        repairs">
  <h4 class="text-block" >exhaust repairs</h4>
</figure>
</li>  
<li>
<figure>
  <img id="pic-two" src="resources/img/2.engine.jpg" alt="engine 
                                                    diagnostics">
    <h4 class="text-block" >exhaust repairs</h4>
</figure>
</ul>
```

However, if you absolutely want to do it in javascript, your problem is that you are looping through all images whenever you hover over one image. Instead, you need to just change the opacity of the image you are hovering on.

```
document.getElementById('pic-' + pictures[i])
  .addEventListener('mouseover',function(){    
    x[i].style.opacity = "1";    
    x[i].style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
  });
```

One more thing though. You are using the variable, `i` to add the listeners. When the mouseover event fires, that variable will have changed and the code will fail. Instead, create a new variable, called `h4` like `var h4 = x[i];` right before you add the event listener. Then, instead of `x[i]...` in the code above, you would use `h4.style.opacity = "1"...`

Comment: Hi Keith. Thanx for help.

Comment: I have now uploaded part of the website I'm working on (a course project) to visualize what I'm facing :
http://demoit.linuxpl.info/w/index.html
The CSS method does work indeed and I have implemented it before however it does not give the smooth effect since you have to hover onto <h4> element which is a thin line in the middle of a picture. I understand there is a fundamental problem with my JS approach as the opacity of a .text-block on mouseover goes to 1 and mouseleave to 0 so when i switch between the pictures the the opacity will not have time to fade in and out so I'm quite gutted.

Comment: I know I can add bckground picture with that text in CSS and let the pictures fade to reveal the text but I'd really like to do it with JS. Any thoughts?